# Ubuntu - get hostname -f to return fake "FQDN" without DNS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hostname

On my private local network, I need an Ubuntu host to convince itself (well, more specifically the Erlang "long name" tool) that it has a FQDN. It doesn't much matter what it is. But supposing my real host name is `apps-dev-01` I'd like `hostname -f` to return, say, `apps-dev-01.internal`.

I'm assuming that some combination of `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf` manipulation will get me there, but I can't figure out what it is exactly. What is the right way here?

Note, I don't run a DNS server internally, and given how small my network is, I'd rather not take on that hassle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an entry in your `/etc/hosts` file such as:

```
your.ip.addr.ess     apps-dev-01
```

You need to change it to

```
your.ip.addr.ess     apps-dev-01.internal   apps-dev-01
```

After that, if you type:

```
$ hostname -f
```

You should get the name: `apps-dev-01.internal`. I am assuming you have the correct config in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` which gives higher priority for DNS resolution using the hosts file.

That's it!

Comment: ah that was it. 3-element host entries.